# finding solution to simultaneous equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have three equations
$$ 
\begin{align*}
      c_1 & = \frac{a}{1+a+b} + \frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{a}{1+a}\\
   c_2 & = \frac{b}{1+a+b} + \frac{b}{a+b}+\frac{b}{1+b}\\
c_3 & = \frac{1}{1+a+b} + \frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b}\\
\end{align*}$$

where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are known constant.

I want to know if I can find $a$ and $b$ or not..

Thanks,

Comment: I would start by multiplying the equations by $a$ or $b$, add them up and try to cancel out some terms. For example $c_2 - b c_3 = \dots$

Comment: You must solve two equations for $a,b$ and plug the solution into the remaining equation.

Comment: The problem looks terrible. The first two equations describe cubic curves and the third a conic. By elimination of one of the unknowns, we can obtain two sextic univariate polynomials. The condition for compatibility of the roots must be daunting, unless some magical simplification occurs.

Comment: Do you know anything more about the constants? Are some of them equal? Which are positive, zero or negative?

Comment: for completeness we can add another equation $c_4 =\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b}$

Comment: If you add the 3 equations together, you get $c_1+c_2+c_3 = 4$, so if your 3 constants don't add to $4$, then the system has no solution.

Comment: if $a=b=1$ they add up to $9/4$

Comment: i was eager to know answer

Comment: @Allawonder constants are positive, but I amnot sure how it will help..

Comment: @ronenp may I know why we need your $c_4$ equation?

Comment: I also know that $a$ and $b$ are positive

Comment: What makes this an especially hard nut, apart from the over-determinacy, is the fact that the exact values of the constants are not known, for it would seem the system behaves very differently for different variations in the values of $c_1,c_2,c_3$.

Answer (score 1):

B. Goddard's great observation effectively answers your question (maybe not even he realises this). I had recognised the importance of his observation immediately, but only saw that it was *the* key on second thoughts, after casting about on the problem for some time.

Your question is whether the system has a solution for every choice of the (positive, according to you) constants $c_i$. Goddard has effectively shown that this is not the case, for a *necessary* condition that the constants must satisfy in order for the system to have a solution is that $\sum{c_i}=4$. It is easy to see that this restriction is also sufficient, so that we have that for every $$0<c_i<4$$ satisfying $$\sum{c_i}=4,$$ your system is soluble. An example is when the $c_i$ are equal, which gives *the* solution $a=b=1$.

Comment: Except that B. Goddard's observation is wrong as is readily seen by picking values for $a,b$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You don't need picking any values, assuming you can add fractions. But please go on, show your favourite counterexample.

Comment: Sorry, my bad .

Comment: @YvesDaoust No worries, dude. It's a common human failing to jump to unfounded conclusions. ☺

Answer (score 0):

Before undertaking calculations which are guaranteed to be tedious, sometimes it helps to graph the equations involved. In this case if we turn these into equations in $x$ and $y$ by letting $x=a$ and $y=b$. Using the graphing site desmos.com and letting $c_1,\,c_2,\,c_3$ be 'sliders' we see that the places where the three graphs contain the same point cannot actually be solutions since they would lead to division by $0$.

For example, $a=x=-1$ and $b=y=0$ involve division by zero, as does $a=x=0$ and $b=y=-1$. We can get a solution $a=x=b=y=0$ but only for the case $c_1=c_2=0$ and $c_3=3$.

There are cases where a common intersection can be obtained but they require specific values of $c_1,\,c_2,\,c_3$. For example, if we let $c_1=c_2=c_3=\frac{4}{3}$ then $a=b=1$ is a solution.

So in general, no, one cannot solve for $a$ and $b$.

Here is the [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gjrqfvfsxy) to the Desmos graphs.